# Errors with the IBM Social Business Toolkit SDK

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, ibm-connections

I’ve tried to work with the Social Business Toolkit from IBM.
Now I have all packages installed the update sites and so on.
I want to start to work with it but I become always the error if I click on any snippet tab in the application, on my server console:

10.02.2015 13:12:22   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in C:/Program Files/IBM/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

10.02.2015 13:12:22   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /abschluss/sbtplayground.nsf/Explorer.xsp - HTTP Code: 500. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in C:/Program Files/IBM/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

In the log is this:

```
<extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:Exception" type="string">
    <values>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.shindig.config.ContainerConfigException&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:73)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:71)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:133)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:245)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:189)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:80)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ManagedBeanFactory$1.run(ManagedBeanFactory.java:222)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:330)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ManagedBeanFactory.newInstance(ManagedBeanFactory.java:216)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createAndMaybeStoreManagedBeans(ApplicationAssociate.java:269)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(</values>
    <values>VariableResolverImpl.java:135)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:71)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.ServerSideLocalObject.resolveVariable(ServerSideLocalObject.java:97)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.ServerSideLocalObject.resolveAttribute(ServerSideLocalObject.java:73)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.AbstractLocalObject._get(AbstractLocalObject.java:119)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.AbstractLocalObject.getPropertyReference(AbstractLocalObject.java:101)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.engine.ProgramContext.findGlobalScopeIdentifier(ProgramContext.java:143)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.engine.ProgramContext.findIdentifier(ProgramContext.java:134)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIdentifier.interpret(ASTIdentifier.java:105)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTMember.interpret(ASTMember.java:106)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:88)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ib</values>
    <values>m.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:365)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:194)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaSc</values>
    <values>riptValueBinding.java:78)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:123)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectItemsEx.getValue(UISelectItemsEx.java:64)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.util.Util.getSelectItems(Util.java:492)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getOptionNumber(MenuRenderer.java:410)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:388)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:357)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:47)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:180)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectOneEx.encodeEnd(UISelectOneEx.java:331)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil</values>
    <values>.java:858)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.dojo.layout.DojoContentPaneRenderer.encodeChildren(DojoContentPaneRenderer.java:195)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.F</values>
    <values>acesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.dojo.layout.DojoContentPaneRenderer.encodeChildren(DojoContentPaneRenderer.java:195)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.layout.AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.renderChildren(AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.java:1401)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.oneuiv302.layout.OneU</values>
    <values>Iv302ApplicationLayoutRenderer.writeContentColumn(OneUIv302ApplicationLayoutRenderer.java:592)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.layout.AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.writeMainContent(AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.java:1105)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.oneuiv302.layout.OneUIv302ApplicationLayoutRenderer.writeMainFrame(OneUIv302ApplicationLayoutRenderer.java:174)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.layout.AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.encodeBegin(AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.java:1367)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:956)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.UIVarPublisherBase.encodeBegin(UIVarPublisherBase.java:112)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUti</values>
    <values>l.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)&#xD;&#xA;</values>
    <values>&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.</values>
    <values>runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)&#xD;&#xA;Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.shindig.config.ContainerConfigException&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:483)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.ecl</values>
    <values>ipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:643)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;... 102 more&#xD;&#xA;</values>
</extendedDataElements>
```

and this

```
<extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:Exception" type="string">
    <values>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.shindig.config.ContainerConfigException&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:73)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:133)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at nsf.playground.beans.APIBean.getToolkitUrl(APIBean.java:64)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:321)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgr</values>
    <values>am.java:119)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:365)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:194)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.</values>
    <values>ibm.xsp.component.UIPassThroughTag$TagAttribute.getValue(UIPassThroughTag.java:114)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.PassThroughTagRenderer.encodeBegin(PassThroughTagRenderer.java:73)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:956)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.ap</values>
    <values>plication.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.Com</values>
    <values>ponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:31</values>
    <values>3)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)&#xD;&#xA;Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.shindig.config.ContainerConfigException&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:483)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:643)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;... 56 more&#xD;&#xA;</values>
</extendedDataElements>
```

I have installed it on a Domino 9.0.1 Server FP2 and my Notes Client is also 9.0.1 FP2

The strange thing is that in my Notes Client can I open it ones. But if I change anything I become just the same error too.

Does anyone have a solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a some what same issue running Domino on ISeries. The problem was that the shindig server was not installed. Can your verify that the server is installed with the command: "tell http osgi ss com.ibm.fiesta"

Comment: yes, that's because the social edition isn't automatically started, you can also disable the loading of that bundle in the manifest.mf of the Playground, and hack out the OpenSocial Explorer.